# Autofac EnableClassInterceptors

Tags: c#, autofac

I am unable to get the Autofac `EnableClassInterceptors` to work. I have been able to get the `EnableInterfaceInterceptors` to work though. I want to use it for logging.

Can anyone see anything obvious I am doing wrong?

This is how I register the type:

```
 var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
 builder.RegisterType<ReceiverManager>()
        .EnableClassInterceptors()
        .InterceptedBy(typeof(MethodCallLogger));
 builder.Register(c => new MethodCallLogger());
```

This is the type I want to intercept:

```
public class ReceiverManager : IManageQueueReceivers
{

    public ReceiverManager(IReceiverHandlerFactory handlerFactory, IListenQueueMessageFactory<QueueMessage> listenerFactory, IBuildQueuePath pathBuilder, ICreateQueue queueCreator, ITestQueueConnection<QueueMessage> connectionTester, ISendRetry<QueueMessage> retrySender, IProcessDeadLetter deadLetterProcessor, ILogger logger)
    {
        ...
    }

    public virtual void CreateReceivers(IEnumerable<QueueConfiguration> queueConfigurationList)
    {
       ...
    }

    public virtual INormalReceiver NormalReceiver(string queuePath, QueueConfiguration configuration)
    {
        ...
    }

    public virtual IReceiver RetryReceiver(string queuePath, QueueConfiguration configuration)
    {
        ...
    }

    public virtual void CreateReceiver(QueueConfiguration configuration, Func<string, QueueConfiguration, IReceiver> receiver, bool testConnection = true)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

This is how I resolve the component:

```
builder.RegisterType<ReceiverManager>()
       .As<IManageQueueReceivers>();
```

Comment: How do you resolve your component ?

Comment: Thanks, Cyril. I have updated with how I resolve the component in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing

```
builder.RegisterType<ReceiverManager>()
       .EnableClassInterceptors()
       .InterceptedBy(typeof(MethodCallLogger));
```

you are registering a `ReceiverManager` as itself and it will be intercepted by the `MethodCallLogger` when you resolve a `ReceiverManager`

ie :

```
scope.Resolve<ReceiverManager>()
     .DoSomething()
```

the `DoSomething` method will be intercepted by `MethodCallLogger`

By adding

```
builder.RegisterType<ReceiverManager>()
       .As<IManageQueueReceivers>();
```

You are registering a new component as `IManageQueueReceivers`. In this case, you will have 2 registrations, one for `ReceiverManager` (which will be intercepted by `MethodCallLogger`) and one for `IManageQueueReceivers`

if you resolve `IManageQueueReceivers` the interceptor won't apply.

The difference between `EnableInterfaceInterceptors` and `EnableClassInterceptors` is how Autofac will provide the type. In the first case, Autofac will create a proxy over the interface, so each method declared by the interface will be intercepted whereas in the second case, Autofac will create a subtype, so each virtual method will be intercepted.

In both case you can only intercept method declared by the type you are resolving.